# Why does Spark's dataset reduce gives different values when using a class?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

When I use this as my reduce function

```
public Integer addCount(Integer integer1, Integer integer2) {
        Integer ret =integer1+integer2;
        return ret;
    }
```

the reduce function given below returns the correct value

```
Integer mapReduce1 = df1.reduce((ReduceFunction<Integer>) mapReduce::addCount);
```

But when I try to use reduce using an object of My class like below:

```
 public MapReducer addCount(MapReducer mapReduce1, MapReducer mapReduce2) {
        MapReducer ret = new MapReducer(mapReduce1.count+ mapReduce2.count);
        return ret;
```

The reduce function returns `correct_value + 5`

```
MapReducer mapReduce1 = df.reduce((ReduceFunction<MapReducer>) mapReduce::addCount);
```

Here MapReducer is a simple class with only one `public` attribute `count` and it's getter and setter

What is going on here? How can I apply rece on a class object properly

MapReducer class:

```
package algorithm;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MapReducer implements Serializable {
    public int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public MapReducer incrementCount(Row row){
        this.count++;
        return this;
    }
    public Integer addCount(Integer integer1, Integer integer2) {
        return integer1+integer2;
    }

    public MapReducer addCount(MapReducer sample1, MapReducer sample2) {

        MapReducer ret = new MapReducer();
        ret.count = sample1.count+ sample2.count;

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Also, I used the following to create the `Dataset`

```
MapReducer sampleMR = new MapReducer();
        Dataset<MapReducer> df = InitialTable.quartetsTable
                .toDF()
                .map
                        (
                                (MapFunction<Row, MapReducer>) sampleMR::incrementCount,
                                Encoders.bean(MapReducer.class)
                        );
```

I was trying to find out the number of rows on each partition of `InitialTable.quartetsTable` which is another `Dataset`

Comment: What is the implementation of your `MapReducer` class ? Can you add it to your question ? Thanks !